# Add producthunt badge to wordpress menu

Tags: customization, menus, html

I'm new to wordpress and i want to add a producthunt badge to the menu of my wordpress site.
I tried editing the page, tried in appearance->menu  but could not find a place to include the block of html provided by producthunt.

my header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

<head>

    <!-- Meta UTF8 charset -->
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, minimal-ui" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#056EB9" />
    <meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#056EB9" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="#056EB9" />
    <?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>

<!-- BODY START -->
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

    <?php techland_preloader(); ?>

    <div id="app">
<?php

        // use this action to add any content before  header container element
        do_action('techland_before_header');
        // include logo, menu and more contents
        techland_header();
        // include logo, menu and widgets contents
        do_action('techland_sidemenu_action');
        // theme back to top button
        techland_backtop();

?>
    <main>
```

Comment: Do you have a child theme active? HTML code usually can't be put in the WP menu, but for that you'll need to edit you `header.php` file. 1. Create a child theme if you're not using this already. 2. Give us the code of the `header.php` and, preferably, a website (or try adding the code yourself somewhere).

Comment: @ralphsmit i have included my header.php code in the quuestion

Comment: @ralphsmit thanks. i managed to edit the header.php file and got what i wanted.Thank you